# how to skip <p> <h2 > <a......> while getting data

Tags: python

i am sorry i dont have proper word to give title. what i am trying to do is this code is fulfilling my requirements by giving me the all text. But problem is that while getting text something like "< p>","< a href....>", "< h1 >", "< h2 >".... are also printing. So anyone who can help me to skip those tags?
my code : (i am using python 2.7.8)

```
import urllib
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse

# Download the RSS feed and parse it
u = urllib.urlopen('http://planet.python.org/rss20.xml')
doc = parse(u)

# Extract and output tags of interest
for item in doc.iterfind('channel/item'):
#    title = item.findtext('title')
#    date = item.findtext('pubDate')
#    link = item.findtext('link')
    des = item.findtext('description')
#    print(title)
#    print(date)
#   print(link)
    print(des)
    print()
```

Comment: Parse the `des` using https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ ??

Comment: i am getting text like this: e.g my xml is <description> <p> i am here <h2> hey me too </h2> and my output is coming as : <p> i am here <h2> he me too </h2>. Can i skip those <p> <h2> </h2> in output>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [BeautifulSoup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to parse the HTML content
Something like this will work if you just need the text. You may parse the HTML, if you need specific information out of the HTML content.

```
import urllib
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

# Download the RSS feed and parse it
u = urllib.urlopen('http://planet.python.org/rss20.xml')
doc = parse(u)

# Extract and output tags of interest
for item in doc.iterfind('channel/item'):
    des = item.findtext('description')
    if des:
        soup = bs(des)
        text = soup.get_text()
        print(text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: is it really skipping the key words of code like <a href....> <p> <h2> while extracting text?

Comment: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/python/s/fyp/New folder/test2.py", line 12, in <module>
    soup = bs(des)
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\bs4\__init__.py", line 162, in __init__
    elif len(markup) <= 256:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()